# chrome://inspect debugger for ionic on android - not the right debugger

Tags: android, google-chrome, ionic-framework, breakpoints, remote-debugging

I used to have chrome://inspect and select the app, It will invoke a window where I can see the whole web-view of my android phone on the browser. And also I can put breakpoints and check variables.

However, Instead when I click in inspect of the app, it comes up [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5rsm.jpg).

I cant put breakpoints or view the screens on the chrome browser.

What has happened, is there a way to get back to the proper chrome debugger.

Comment: have you tried **debugger;** command inside your coding.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the "Sources" tap on the top.
That should give you an overview of the files to add breakpoints, etc...